# Resources for Polyadic and/or Cylindric Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory

I'm looking to learn a little bit about polyadic and cylindric algebras, as part of an investigation into algebraic approaches to logic.

The only "text" that I can find for polyadic algebra is Halmos' and I've got to be honest, I don't like Halmos' writing style. (I've tried two different texts from him and the style doesn't work for me.)

For cylindric the only thing I can find there is the two volume series from Tarski, Henkin, and Monk. I can't seem to locate Part I in my library, and it seems hard to find to purchase.

I've found some limited papers which may suffice to give me an idea of what is going on, but I was wondering if anyone knew of any other papers/textbooks that had bits about these algebras?

Also as an additional question, I'm wondering whether it is worth my time to pursue polyadic/cylindric algebras. Have the category theory approaches to logic become more valuable than polyadic and/or cylindric approaches?

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: 2017 update:  I have found the 1st volume of "Cylindric Algebra", it's available for download online.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this, I'd wanted to ask almost the exact same question, word for word!

I don't have a very good answer, but I think the introductory book by Halmos and Givant 1988 ("Logic as algebra") is helpful.  Is that one of the 2 books you mentioned?  Knowing some algebraic geometry (such as the use of ideals) may help in understanding the book.

See also my question:
[simple exercise in Cylindric algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874485/simple-exercise-in-cylindric-algebra)

I'd like to discuss / share more ideas when I have time...